# maven tycho load properties file for p2 repo locations

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

I want to have an external properties file with the locations of local p2 mirrors used in build, something like:

```
mirror.location=/my/mirror/location
```

I want this to be an external file because I want to use it in maven and also in other scripts and I want to avoid having to duplicate the location in different languages.

I found out that I should use properties-maven-plugin to do that as follows

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <files>
                    <file>locations.properties</file>
                </files>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I would then want to use the read property in the repositories url in the same pom file

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>eclipse_mirror</id>
        <url>${mirror.location}/eclipse/</url>
        <layout>p2</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

The problem is that Maven/Tycho loads the repositories well before any phase in the lifecycle and prints out this error

`[INFO] Computing target platform for MavenProject: ...
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid repository URL: ${mirror.location}/eclipse/: no protocol: ${mirror.location}/eclipse/ -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid repository URL: ${mirror.location}/eclipse/`

Any clues on how to use a properties file to specify repository urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that Maven/Tycho loads the repositories well before any phase in the lifecycle and prints out this error

This observation is correct. As long as [Bug 353889](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353889) is not fixed, you cannot use the `properties-maven-plugin` to manipulate properties whose value Tycho requires during dependency resolution.

That being said, are you aware that you can [declare mirrors](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform/Authentication_and_Mirrors) in Maven’s `setting.xml`? This is IMHO a better place to declare settings likes mirrors, as you can then ensure that your main build build (as specified in the `pom.xml`) is self-contained, i.e., doesn't require external knowledge like system properties.

Lastly, note that you can reference environment variables like `${env.HOME}` in your [`settings.xml`](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html). If you put your variables in a file and let the shell source it before the `mvn` invocation, you can re-use that file in other places as well (although it’s not 100% `.properties` file format).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the notes. I used the settings.xml file to mirror repository and I can basically do what I want, not as clean as I hoped, but good enough for now. Thanks a lot.